# App Rotating Even Though I Told it Not To

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Wrote an app with Xcode. Clicked the buttons that restrict orientations to be the two portrait options. Changed the plist file to only allow the two portrait orientations. Put the restriction in programatically.

When I build the app to my phone, it rotates into both landscapes and the upright portrait orientation. What the heck?

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) ||
            (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown));
            }
```

Comment: Added the only relevant code. I thought that writing this was redundant after the plist and buttons were dealt with, but none of them seem to have any effect.

Comment: more code would need to be added to debug this issue
the way that the viewcontroller is initialized would help (note if its by nib verify that the view controller is properly hooked up and its not using a generic uiviewcontroller)

Comment: Double-checking the view controller. That could be it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you're using is part of the controller class, but that method may never get called if the controller class is either not active or not in control of the view on the screen.  So your app might be auto rotating because this message is in fact never actually getting called.  The solution is to check the connections or initializations of your view controller class to make sure that they are running as you expect.